# Magento site allowed in canada only

Tags: magento, proxy

I have blocked my magento site in all over the world except canada, now i am unable to access the site. Please tell me any canadian Proxy site which can open it in india to login admin

Comment: (Must admit this is the funniest question I've ever read in stackoverflow!) I presume you've done it through htaccess or similar? Can't you edit it to let your IP address through?

Answer (score 0):

Change your IP to Canada IP using Cyber Host software then you will able to access your website's admin section.

Answer (score 0):

Where/How have you limited the country? this could mean a different solution..

You could use FoxyProxy (or similar) extension for firefox/chrome and change the country your IP is coming from - and then access your site.

If you have access to the database you could always connect and change any settings manually to disable the country lock (if you've done this inside magento itself of course)